# What's the proof for the formula for the local time of a Semimartingale?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, local-time

I'm currently studying Local times of Semimartingales and I came across the following formula for the local time at $a$ of $X \in S_c$:
$$ L_t^a (X) = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{2\varepsilon} \int_0^t \mathbb{1}_{(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)}(X_s) dX_s $$
However, I'm stuck on the proof (and have looked online and in textbooks but with no success). Here's my attempt thus far:

The occupation formula states that for a non-negative function $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$:
$$\int_0^t \phi(X_s) d\langle X \rangle_s = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi (u) L_t^u du$$
Putting $\phi := (2\varepsilon)^{-1} \mathbb{1}_{(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)}$ I obtain:
$$L_{t,\epsilon}^a := \frac{1}{2\varepsilon}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{1}_{(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)}(u) L_t^u du = \int_0^t \frac{1}{2\varepsilon}\mathbb{1}_{(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)}(X_s) d\langle X \rangle_s $$
Now here's the kicker. I want to justify taking the limit $\varepsilon \to 0$ inside the integral on the LHS so that $L_{t,\epsilon}^a \to L_t^a (X)$ (using a property of the dirac delta function at a). However, I can't see how to suitably bound the integral on the RHS (unless we have a BM in which case it's not to bad) because I was thinking of using DCT (as I did with the BM case).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By the Lebesgue differentiation theorem,

$$\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\varepsilon} \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)}L_t^udu = \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\varepsilon} \int_{B(a,\varepsilon)} L_t^udu = L_t^a $$ for almost every $a$.  Therefore, based on the occupation formula computation you did, $$L_t^a = \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\varepsilon} \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)} = \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\varepsilon} \int_{0}^t 1_{(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)}(X_s)d\langle X \rangle_s $$  You don't need to take the limit inside the integral on the right because this is the formula for local time you wanted.

Comment: Sorry I meant taking a limit of the LHS (my bad). However, your solution looks simpler than trying DCT